# Rails not picking up css specific files, picks up sass fine though

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This one is not holding me up, but I'm really curious what is happening.

I have in my application.css:

```
*= require_self
*= require conversations
```

and have some styles defined in my *conversations.css*, but they would not get picked up!

By chance, I renamed to *conversations.css.scss* and suddenly it started working. I renamed back to .css and it stopped.

I thought you could have either .css or .scss files and they would get picked up by rails (my version is 3.2.11)

**Edit**: I also tried this for .js files and the same behaviour.  As soon as I add .coffee to any .js file, it gets picked up and used, otherwise, it does not.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before?  If so, what is going on?

Comment: where do you place your css file? `app/assets/stylesheets`?

Comment: I think seeing more of your code in context would be helpful. `*= require conversations` alone isn't very useful.

Comment: Sorry, the code is simple css markup, the conversations.css.scss is in the same directory as the application.css, in the app/assets/stylesheets.  It's definitely being applied if it's called .scss, just not with the .css extension alone.

Comment: I'd like to offer help, but it's hard to with nothing to go off of except `*= require conversations` and your explanation of setup that should not result in the issue you're having. `*= require conversations` doesn't care what the extension is, as long as it starts with a `.css`. Even `conversations.css.scss.erb` will be included.

Comment: Thanks @Deefour, I don't know what else to add, there's nothing else in my application.css and my conversations.css.scss has a ton of styling, it all works, but as soon as I rename it to a .css the style is not picked up.  I agree with you that it should be picked up, but it's not...